# Azure suggester returning all content

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to implement an Azure suggester feature into our pilot Azure search app and running into issues.  The content I'm indexing are PDF files, so my suggester definition is based on the content field itself which can be thousands of lines of text.  Following examples online, when I implement the suggester, I'm returned the entire content of the body of text from the PDF file.  What I'd really like to do is return just a phrase found in the text.

For instance, suppose I'm indexing a Harry Potter book and I type into my search field "Dum", I'd like to see suggested results back like "Dumbledore", "Dementor", etc VS the whole book.  Is this possible?

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to search for words sharing the same prefix, Autocomplete is the right API for this job. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/autocomplete

In contrast, Suggester API helps users find the documents containing words with that prefix. It returns text snippets containing those worlds.

If you still believe suggester api does not behave as expected and autocomplete is not suitable, let me know your source document, query and expected results.

Comment: Thanks Rudin,  My source document is a PDF containing the contents of Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone.  The suggester field is created on this content and is called "SG".  The query is this:

SuggestParameters sp = new SuggestParameters()
{
     UseFuzzyMatching = true,
     Top = 5
};
DocumentSuggestResult resp = _indexClient.Documents.Suggest(term, "SG", sp);

The query is "Harry P...".  The results I'd like to see are "otter" show up as autocomplete text.

Comment: Have you tried autocomplete API in my response? It seems autocomplete is what you want instead of suggester.

Comment: Sorry - the link you posted didn't include a full example of how to implement.  My additional research led me back to an article which seemed to fit the bill, but was implementing the Suggest APIs again.  After mucking about, got it working with Autocomplete and jQuery.  Tks for the assist.